# Exchange 2010 Distribution Group - Email Self

Tags: exchange-2010, groups

In exchange 2010 we have multiple distribution groups.

If i am a member of group TEST, and i send an email to this group, i will receive the email.
Is there a way of sending to everyone in the group but exclude myself automaticaly?

I know you can expand the group in outlook and manually remove myself, but just curious if there is an option somewhere that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send mail to a distribution group, it will go to all members of that group, including the sender.

There is no way to disable/configure this behavior.