# Receiving own email in distribution group in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange

Is there a way to exclude the sender from delivery on distribution group emails when try are a member of that group in Exchange 2010? This was easy with a simple checkbox in Exchange 2003, but googling I can find no simple way to do this in Exchange 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is currently no way of doing this in Exchange 2010. This have previously been mentioned in this question: [Exchange 2010 Distribution Group - Email Self](https://serverfault.com/questions/230930/exchange-2010-distribution-group-email-self)